# Value Stored to during its initialization is never read when assigning a frame

Tags: iphone

```
CGRect bannerFrame = testView.frame;
bannerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 236, 480, 32);
testView.frame = bannerFrame;
```

I get **Value stored to 'bannerFrame' during its initialization is never read** this warning in analyze. How can i resolve it ??

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `testView.frame` initially is useless as you have assigned `CGRectMake(0, 236, 480, 32);` in very next line. So do it as follows...

```
CGRect bannerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 236, 480, 32);
testView.frame = bannerFrame;
```

Now analyzer will not complain :)